# How do I parse a fragment with JSoup that starts with a <tr>?

Tags: jsoup

Using JSoup, I am trying to parse a `<tr>` tag outside of it's context. From what I read in the JSoup docs, this should be possible:

https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-body-fragment: *You have a fragment of body HTML (e.g. a div containing a couple of p tags; as opposed to a full HTML document) that you want to parse.*

When I use parseFragment on `<tr><div>text</div></tr>` and then use `document.body().html()`, it return only the div. That on itself makes sense as a tr inside document/body is not valid.

Is there any other way to parse that fragment without having it added to a document body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xmlParser`. It will skip HTML validations and get the document exactly as your input.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

Comment: We ended up moving away from JSoup, but this suggestion defnitely helped to move forward.